# Call AppBarLayout.offsetChaged()

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I use CollapsingToolbarLayout in my application. On collapse or expand I fade layout inside. I disabled **AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener** when fading is in progress to avoid wrong behavior.

Now when I swipe fast (e.g down and up) my app ignores the second scroll and layout stays faded. When the second scroll ends I want to compare offset before and after the animation and then call **callOffsetChanged()** or something so it runs through onOffsetChangedListener again.